# How to know when someone has clicked on an Adview?

Tags: android, click, adview

I'm using an adview in my application and want to know when someone has clicked that Adview!
How I can do that?
The onclicklistener does not seem to work.

Comment: can you post your code plz , and your xml too :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the listener this way:

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```

And then implement this:

```
@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
//OnClick here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The click is handled inside of the AdMob API, and I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking with the API as its against the TOS to use a "unlock feature by clicking X number of ads" model.  For that reason I don't believe it is available in the API where the onclicklistener is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    super.onAdOpened();

                }
            });
```